# how to debug aspnetcore Microsoft.Extensions*.dll by Microsoft.Extensions*.pdb?

Tags: asp.net-core, debugging

Recently I compiled dotent runtime source 6.0.1 and aspnetcore source 6.0.1, and used Rider to debug aspnetcore project. Basically all dlls can be debugged with breakpoints, only Microsoft.Extensions.* cannot. Rider Debug Console outputs something like : 
 **"Loaded Assembly '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'

Loading module /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll in application domain 1:clrhost 

Pdb file for assembly /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll was not found or failed to read ”** , 
 about 25 Microsoft.Extensions The .* pdb files are not getting after compiling the source code. How to get these pdb files? And how to set up to debug Microsoft.Extensions.*.dll? Not using SourceLink etc.

Comment: os：Macos; IDE: Rider。

Comment: other dll can load pdb file, like: <br/> 
Symbols for module /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll loaded